# Cytoscape.js node/edge label editor on label tap/click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cytoscape.js

Is there any library that can provide edit capabilities on node/edge labels? I have searched all over npm and github and I haven't found anything useful. A library close to my needs is 'zngduong/cytoscape.js-edit-content' but it is not working properly. I implemented context menu and one of the options I created is to edit the element's label. I am having trouble in spawning an input tag on the element's position. Below is my current code using [this](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu) library.

`cy.cxtmenu({
                    selector: 'node, edge',
                    commands: [
                        {
                            content: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>',
                            select: function(ele)
                            {
                                var $input = '<input type="text" value="'+ ele.data('name') +'" size="20" style="z-index: 10000;"/>'; 
                                $('div#cy').append($input);
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            content: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>',
                            select: function(ele){
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            content: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>',
                            select: function(ele){
                                ele.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) You can't append anything to the Cytoscape div.

(2) You should be storing the label text in the element's [data](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.data).

(3) You should be using the [stylesheet](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style) to [map](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/mappers) a data field to the label (e.g. `label: data(label)`).

(4) By (3) and (4), setting `node.data('label', newLabel)` changes the label text.  How you design your UI for this is open for you to decide.  For example, you could show a text box in a [qtip](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip).